Can't connect/write stream from spark container to table in cassandra container
I am composing these services in separate docker containers all on the same confluent network:
broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    volumes: 
      - ./spark_stream.py:/opt/bitnami/spark/spark_stream.py
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    networks:
      - confluent

  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    networks:
      - confluent
    volumes: 
      - ./spark_stream.py:/opt/bitnami/spark/spark_stream.py

  cassandra_db:
    image: cassandra:latest
    container_name: cassandra
    hostname: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    environment:
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=512M
      - HEAP_NEWSIZE=100M
      - CASSANDRA_USERNAME=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
    networks:
      - confluent


# Define the networks
networks:
  confluent:

I create a spark connection like this:
s_conn = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkDataStreaming') \
            .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'cassandra') \
            .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042") \
            .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra") \
            .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra") \
            .getOrCreate()

And cassandra connection like this:
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='cassandra', password='cassandra')
cluster = Cluster(['localhost'], port=9042, auth_provider=auth_provider, connect_timeout=60)
cas_session = cluster.connect()

The spark connection reads from a kafka stream (also on same network) into a dataframe like this:
spark_df = spark_conn.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'broker:29092') \
            .option('subscribe', 'users_created') \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
            .load()

I write the dataframe to cassandra using this:
streaming_query = (spark_df.writeStream.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                               .option('checkpointLocation', '/tmp/checkpoint')
                               .option('keyspace', 'spark_streams')
                               .option('table', 'created_users')
                               .start())

When I try writing the dataframe to cassandra I get this error:
ERROR CassandraConnectorConf: Unknown host 'cassandra'
java.net.UnknownHostException: cassandra: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

And this is how I call my spark job (I believe with the right packages attached):
spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 --packages "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.3" --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra --conf spark.cassandra.connection.port=9042 spark_stream.py

I thought the spark connection would connect to cassandra, but it seems it can't find the host or contact point?
I tried changing spark.cassandra.connection.host to localhost or 127.0.0.1. For some reason localhost gives me a different error message:
ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
24/11/14 01:59:40 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support MicroBatchWrite[epoch: 0, writer: CassandraBulkWrite(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@105fe638,com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector@4d392247,TableDef(spark_streams,created_users,ArrayBuffer(ColumnDef(id,PartitionKeyColumn,VarCharType)),ArrayBuffer(),Stream(ColumnDef(address,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(email,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(first_name,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(gender,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(last_name,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(phone,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(picture,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(post_code,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(registered_date,RegularColumn,VarCharType), ColumnDef(username,RegularColumn,VarCharType)),Stream(),false,false,Map()),WriteConf(RowsInBatch(5),1000,Partition,LOCAL_QUORUM,false,false,5,None,TTLOption(DefaultValue),TimestampOption(DefaultValue),true,None),StructType(StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(first_name,StringType,true),StructField(last_name,StringType,true),StructField(gender,StringType,true),StructField(address,StringType,true),StructField(post_code,StringType,true),StructField(email,StringType,true),StructField(username,StringType,true),StructField(registered_date,StringType,true),StructField(phone,StringType,true),StructField(picture,StringType,true)),org.apache.spark.SparkConf@5ac2dede)] is aborting.

I don't believe it's an error with column mismatches, but I could be wrong. I can see the data appear in the kafka topic through a confluent control-center I set up, so I know the data is making it that far.
Any help would be appreciated.
